# how to simplexml_load_file file URI stream with special characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to simplexml_load_file the content.opf in an ebook where the ebook filename is `1A!@#$%^&*()_+'".=@:0.epub`

It fails:

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(zip://...@#$%^&*()_+'".=@:0.epub#content.opf): failed to open stream: operation failed in load.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "zip://1A!@#$%^&*()_+'".=@:0.epub#content.opf" in load.php on line 3
```

I've tried a various combination of addslashes, rawurlencode, urlencode, escapeshellarg, utf8_encode to no avail.

Comment: Where do the `zip://` coming from? Do you have registered a protocol handler which handles `zip://` URLs?

Comment: Using the zip stream handler https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php